# Problemas loguendo un Usuario en flask_login

Tags: flask

Buenas estoy empezando con Flask. Estoy haciendo un microservicio user y tengo tres ficheros app.py, models.py, routes.py.

En el método login(), justo despues de ejecutar el login_user inclui en la respuesta
información de current_user para verificar

```
login_user(user)

response = {'message':  'logged in ',
            'api_key':  user.api_key,
            'logeado':  current_user.is_authenticated,
            'username': current_user.username }
```

current_user.is_authenticated me da False y current_user.username contiene el nombre
del Usuario que acaba de loguearse. El primero debería ser True segun creo.

Después tengo un método asociado a la raíz del microservicio que me devuelve el nombre
del Usuario logueado o me devuelve un mensaje indicando que no hay nadie logueado.

```
def get_current_user():
print(current_user.username)
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return make_response(jsonify({'result': current_user.username}), 200)
else:
    return make_response(jsonify({'message': "User not logged in"}), 401)
```

El print(current_user.username) lo puse para chequear que tenía current_user, parecido a lo que hice en el login(), pero me salta un error porque current_user esta instanciado con la
clase
AnonymousUserMixin

error:
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'username'

que por lo que leí es la clase asignada por defecto a current_user mientras no haya algún Usuario logueado. No sé que es lo que pasa que no instancia la clase User en current_user, bueno si lo hace pero como si la perdiera, porque en el login pregunto por current_user.username y me responde correctamente, pero al salir del método login() vuelve a tener la clase AnonymousUserMixin. Lo llamativo es que incluso dentro del login() current_user.is_authenticated me da False cuando deberí dar True. Creo que ahí está el problema pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.